# Install disk 2 of windows server 2003 from USB

Tags: usb, windows-server-2003, bootable

I am trying to put windows server 2003 from disk to a bootable USB. I have downloaded the software WinToFlash and it has worked, now my USB is bootable with windows 2003.

My only problem is, ow do I install disk 2 of windows server 2003? Do I create another bootable USB of it and connect it to the server?

If anyone has any information it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disk 2 is not needed for installation, so you can install Windows from USB and then copy all files from Disk2 to machine to install addtional applications and services (OS will ask location of this files when needed).